# Why is this JSON schema not assignable to this TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv'

interface ExpectedBody {
    repository: {
      name: string,
    }
    push: {
      changes: [{
        old: {
          name: string,
        },
        new: {
          name: string,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
  
  const expectedBodySchema: JSONSchemaType<ExpectedBody> = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      repository: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          name: {
            type: 'string',
          },
        },
        required: ['name'],
      },
      push: {
        type: 'object',
        properties: {
          changes: {
            type: 'array',
            minItems: 0,
            items: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                old: {
                  type: 'string',
                },
                new: {
                  type: 'string',
                },
              },
              required: ['old', 'new']
            },
          },
        },
        required: ['changes']
      }
    },
    required: ['repository', 'push'],
  }
```

I get the ts error

> Type '{ type: "object"; properties: { repository: { type: "object"; properties: { name: { type: "string"; }; }; required: "name"[]; }; push: { type: "object"; properties: { changes: { type: "array"; minItems: 0; items: { ...; }; }; }; required: "changes"[]; }; }; required: ("repository" | "push")[]; }' is not assignable to type 'UncheckedJSONSchemaType<ExpectedBody, false>'.
> The types of 'properties.push' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ type: "object"; properties: { changes: { type: "array"; minItems: 0; items: { type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }; }; }; required: "changes"[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ changes: [{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }]; }, false> & { const?: { changes: [{ old: { name: string; }; new: { ...; }; }]; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; })'.
> The types of 'properties.changes' are incompatible between these types.
> Type '{ type: "array"; minItems: 0; items: { type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ $ref: string; } | (UncheckedJSONSchemaType<[{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }], false> & { const?: [{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }] | undefined; enum?: readonly [...][] | undefined; default?: [...] | undefined; })'.
> Type '{ type: "array"; minItems: 0; items: { type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "array"; items: readonly [UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }, false> & { const?: { old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; }] & { ...; }; minItems: 1; } & { ...; } & { ...; ...'.
> Type '{ type: "array"; minItems: 0; items: { type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "array"; items: readonly [UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }, false> & { const?: { old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; }] & { ...; }; minItems: 1; }'.
> Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
> Type '{ type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'readonly [UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }, false> & { const?: { old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; }] & { ...; }'.
> Type '{ type: string; properties: { old: { type: string; }; new: { type: string; }; }; required: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'readonly [UncheckedJSONSchemaType<{ old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; }, false> & { const?: { old: { name: string; }; new: { name: string; }; } | undefined; enum?: readonly { ...; }[] | undefined; default?: { ...; } | undefined; }]'.ts(2322)

Despite the verbose error message I don't understand what is wrong. Do you understand what is wrong?

Comment: Would be easier to debug if you start with the smaller schema

Comment: That's a good point, I'll try to start small instead

Comment: `old` and `new` are containers for `name` properties - you're missing that in the data

Comment: Thanks @Rycochet, I see that now after you pointed it out. It's still not working, but I'm trying to figure it out with smaller parts.